# Is the name of my app also the name of my bot?

Tags: c#, botframework

When I test my bot on dev.botframework.com, all the messages coming from my bot shows my app name. Is it possible to re-name it? I haven't quite decided on a nice, friendly bot name, so I am trying out a few names every few days.

Can I also change the name of the user from "You" to the actual user's name when I gather it during conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name of the bot displayed in the WebChat control by changing the Dispaly name field on the Bot profile under Settings @ dev.botframework.com.  There's no way to change the "You" text for the iframed webchat.

However, you can host the WebChat control on a page and provide the BotChat control with User and Bot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid', name: 'user name' },
        bot: { id: 'botid', name: 'bot name' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the bot's name without changing the app name?

If I do change it from MyProject123 to CustomerHelp then it changes the whole bot name under My Bots, and I find that confusing especially since we are sharing this bot in a team.

Comment: Yes: hosting the WebChat control on a page, and providing BotChat with User and Bot.